# Selective user registration using django_registration?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-registration

I have a site catering to multiple clubs, and each club has administrators who maintain a database of club members.  I want to limit site registration only to members who have explicitly been added to the club's database.  **How do I go about auto-generating and sending out registration links to members as they are added to the database?**  In other words, I want registration to be initiated only by club administrators.

Comment: If "they are sent a registration link", include a guid in the link that is also stored in the database. When they click the link, compare the guid to the value in the database before confirming their registration. I believe django_registration includes ways for you to subclass or create your own registration backend to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify.  I currently do not have the system sending out the registration link...that's part of the functionality I want to implement.  All I have now is them clicking a link on the login page that says "Register Now," leaving me open to the random people problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit registrations to people already in the database, you will need some way to identify them.

1. Require the club administrator to enter an email address for each member entered.
2. Require the user to supply that address when registering.
3. Send the registration link to that address, including the primary key of the user record in the link.
4. When the user clicks the link, in your django view examine the link and make sure the key matches, then complete the registration.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have a database of club members already, so you must have a primary key or a tuple  which is unique for that database like a **club registration number**
which club members should know already

1. Tell Users to give there primary key value(**club registration number**) at the time of registration.
2. Make that club registration number also as a primary key to the new database which you  are creating after registration for the user, next time if some body will re-use that club registration number to re-register then ***It will fail as the database tuple will already be there associated with that club registration number***
3. Also have a warning message at the time of registration ***that you can use one club registration number for one registration only for the site.***